# how to Autofill form entries when user is logged in?

Tags: php, html

sir,i want to know the sample code of creating a page in php which would contain all the basic details of register user currently logged in.i have entered name,address,empid(primary key),designation,department name,joining date at the time of registration.i want in my form that these details woluld already appear in  their respective fields,so that user has to enter only few information in subsequent forms.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

So did you store those datas in the database?

If so, try to get them from the database:

```
Username: <input value<="<?php echo getData('username'); ?>">
Address: <input value<="<?php echo getData('address'); ?>">
... MORE ...
```

and the `getData()` should looks like this:

```
function getData($fieldName)
{
    $db = new MysqliDb ('host', 'username', 'password', 'databaseName');

    /** The user id, you can set this like $_SESSION['userId'], 
        it's about how you make user "logged in" */
    $userId = 1;

    return $db->where('userId', $userId)
              ->getOne('users', $fieldName);
}
```

I will suggest you to use [this MySQLi Class](https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class), it's very simple to get the datas from the database.